# Handle null value of a field in a class in a function outside that class in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-null-safety

```
class StuffContainer(var stuff: MutableList<String>?) {
    fun appendSomeStuff(newStuff: List<String>) { // Appends to stuff, initialising it if null
        stuff?.addAll(newStuff) ?: let { stuff = ArrayList<String>(newStuff) }
    }
}

fun main (args: Array<String>) {
    val container = StuffContainer(null)

    val arr : ArrayList<String> = ArrayList()
    arr.add("abc")
    arr.add("bcd")

    // Now I want to put arr in container
    container.appendSomeStuff(arr)
    println(container.stuff) // [abc, bcd]

    // That worked. Now how to implement the logic in StuffContainer.appendSomeStuff here?
    container.stuff = null
    //container.stuff?.addAll(arr) ?: let { container.stuff = ArrayList<String>(arr) }
    // Can't write a let expression here

    if (container.stuff == null) {
        container.stuff = ArrayList<String>(arr)
    } else {
        container.stuff?.addAll(arr)
    }
    println(container.stuff) // [abc, bcd]
}
```

That's a stripped down version of the code I have. In the code above I have written a main so that it's possible to copy and execute it. But in actual usage I have a function which gets a "StuffContainer" object as an argument.

I can't figure out how to properly handle null values of fields in a class in a function that's defined outside that class.
I can't use a let expression so I'm using an if-else block.

Is that the best way to do this?
Despite all kotlin's attempts to avoid bugs due to vars being set to null from somewhere, this code won't work properly when "container" *is* set to null just after the if block's null check. Is there a better way?

Comment: no. I need to initialise container.stuff (and call some other logic if possible) when it's null

Answer (score 0):

**TLDR**:

You want to do something like this.

```
 when {
        container.stuff == null -> container.stuff = ArrayList<String>(arr)
        else -> container.stuff?.addAll(arr)
    }
```

OR

```
 container.stuff = container.stuff ?: ArrayList(arr)
```

*There probably are better ways to do it.*

**Explanation** :

You're expecting to use something like this

```
container.stuff?.addAll(arr) ?: let { container.stuff = ArrayList<String>(arr) }
```

> What's wrong with I was doing?

Firstly, the way you're currently using the `let` method seems slightly wrong. The `let` function is invoked on a particular data item, where the evaluated expression is passed to the lambda.

The function is only invoked if the expression evaluates to NOT null.

> Why it's wrong?

- The let function isn't called that way

> Will this work?

```
container.stuff?.addAll(arr)?.let { container.stuff = ArrayList<String>(arr) }
```

This will also not work, since your `container.stuff` is null, so the `addAll` function would not be called, and hence, it wouldn't enter the `let` block.